# Embedded YouTube videos have sound but no video

Tags: cyanogenmod, chrome-for-android, video, youtube

Whenever I come across a page with an embedded YouTube video and press play then the sound will be heard but the video will be blank (a black screen).

The controls work just fine - it's just that I don't have any video.

If I attempt to rotate the phone to landscape, then the video will briefly show just before the screen is rotated and then go back to being black again. Sound will continue to play just fine. If I attempt to rotate the phone back to portrait then the same thing happens again.

This problem occurs in Chrome, but also in any apps where the browser has been embedded (eg. Feedly and Facebook).

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S3 (i9300) running CM11-20141115-SNAPSHOT-M12-i9300.

Is there any way I can resolve this?

Comment: I had the very same issue with my RSS reader on the *Optimus 4X* (running a stock Android 4.0.4). Always thought it was the app, as it worked with different other RSS apps – until I found out it worked with the very same app on my secondary device (Moto Milestone 2 running CM10 / Android 4.1). So I second Dan's assumption: a bug in the ROM / Android version is a pretty likely cause.

Comment: Same problem over here (i9300, CM11 - I had the problem with various versions, previous M builds as well as the latest nightly). I do have video in full screen mode. Tried that?

Comment: I found these related bug reports : 
https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/browse/CYAN-5012
https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/browse/CYAN-5271

https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/browse/CYAN-5952
https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/browse/NIGHTLIES-480

Comment: Have you updated **Android System WebView**?  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is only with embedded videos, just click on the link to the actual video on Youtube. Or try long pressing on it to get the link to the video URL.